# Reference error not detected: undefined

Tags: javascript, constructor

Bueno estoy haciendo un carrito de compras, y quiero que los datos de los productos se redirijan a un index.html

Disculpen pero me surgió un problema en `compra.js` `new Carrito` marca el Error de referencia no detectado: no está definido, pero por mas que revise no se que anda mal aquí esta mi html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Silver's </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">

    <!--Google Font link-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonticons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootsnav.css">


    <!--For Plugins external css-->

    <!--Theme custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!--Theme Responsive css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css" />

    <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">



        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed white no-background bootsnav">
            <!-- Start Top Search -->
            <div class="top-search">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-addon close-search"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Top Search -->

            <div class="container">    
                <!-- Start Atribute Navigation -->
                <div class="attr-nav">
                    <ul cols="8">
                        <li style="font-size: 17px; margin-top: -1px;"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <!--<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>
                                <span class="badge">3</span>
                            </a>-->
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu cart-list">

                                <!---- More List ---->

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                       <!-- <li class="search"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>-->
                         <li class="side-menu" style="margin-top: 1px;"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
                         </ul>
                </div>        

                    <a class="navbar-brand">

                        <img src="assets/images/SILVER'S .png"
                        style="width: 75px;height: 75px; margin-top: -12px;" class="logo logo-display m-top-10" alt="">
                        <img src="assets/images/SILVER'S .png"
                        style="width: 75px;height: 75px; margin-top: -12px;" class="logo logo-scrolled" alt="">

                    </a>
                    <h1 class="titulo">
                        Silver's online store</h1>

                <!-- End Header Navigation -->

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" data-in="fadeInDown" data-out="fadeOutUp">
                        <li><a href="#hello"></a></li>                    
                        <!--<li><a href="#about">Uso</a></li>-->                    
                        <li><a href="#service"></a></li>                    
                        <li><a href="#portfolio"></a></li>                    
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>  


            <!-- Start Side Menu -->
            <div class="side">
                <a href="#" class="close-side"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                <div class="widget menu2">
                    <h6 class="title">Categorías</h6>
                    <ul class="link">
                        <li><a href="electrónica.html">Electrónica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="joyería.html">Joyería</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bisutería.html">Bisutería</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End Side Menu -->

        </nav>


        <!--Home Sections-->

        <section class="electronicajpg bg-mega">
            <div class="overlay-electronica"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="main_home-electronica">
                        <div>
                            <p class="cate">Bolsa de compra</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--End off row-->
           </div> <!--End off container -->
        </section> <!--End off Home Sections-->


        <!--About Sections-->
        <section id="about" class="about roomy-70">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row mt-3">
                            <div class="col">
                                <form id="procesar-pago" action="#">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="cliente" class="col-12 col-md-2 col-form-label h2">Cliente :</label>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cliente"
                                                placeholder="Ingresa nombre cliente" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="email" class="col-12 col-md-2 col-form-label h2">Correo :</label>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
            
                                    <div id="carrito" class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table" id="lista-compra">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">Imagen</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Sub Total</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                                                </tr>
            
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
            
                                            </tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-right">SUB TOTAL :</th>
                                                <th scope="col">
                                                    <p id="subtotal"></p>
                                                </th>
                                                <!-- <th scope="col"></th> -->
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-right">TOTAL :</th>
                                                <th scope="col">
                                                    <p id="total"></p>
                                                </th>
                                                <!-- <th scope="col"></th> -->
                                            </tr>
            
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
            
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center" id="loaders">
                                        <img id="cargando" src="assets/images/Portfolio/cargando.gif" width="220">
                                    </div>
            
                                    <div class="row justify-content-between">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                            <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="procesar-compra">Realizar compra</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
            
                            </div>
            
            
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
                                    
             </div>
                             <!--End off row-->
            </div><!--End off container -->
        </section> <!--End off About section -->



        <!--Contact Us Section-->
        <section id="contact" class="contact bg-mega fix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="main_contact roomy-60 text-white">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div>
                            <div class="social-btn-container">
                             <!-- <span class="social-btn-box"> <a href="https://plus.google.com/116499013539302933204" class="google-plus-btn"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a> </span><!-- /.social-btn-box --> 
                              <span class="social-btn-box"> 
                                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Silvers-106724711840234" 
                                  class="facebook-btn"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> </span><!-- /.social-btn-box --> 

                              <span class="social-btn-box"> 
                                  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9991997715&text=Hola, Nececito mas informacion!" 
                                  class="Whatsapp-btn"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a> </span><!-- /.social-btn-box --> 
                             <!-- <span class="social-btn-box"> <a href="https://hr.linkedin.com/in/valeron-design-studio-37021a37" class="linkedin-btn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> </span><!-- /.social-btn-box --> 
                             <!-- <span class="social-btn-box"> <a href="#" class="youtube-btn"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a> </span><!-- /.social-btn-box --> 
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--End off row -->
            </div><!--End off container -->
        </section><!--End off Contact Section-->



        <footer id="footer" class="footer bg-black">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="main_footer text-center p-top-40 p- 
    bottom-30">
                        <p class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" 
    style="color: white;">
                            Silver's 2022. Todos los derechos reservados
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- JS includes -->

        <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootsnav.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/compra.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/carrito.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

También les dejo el `carrito.js,` el que me sirve es `leerLocalStorageCompra` que está enlazado con el que me da problemas

```
class Carrito {


//añadir a bolsa
comprarProducto(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.target.classList.contains('agregar-carrito')){
        const producto = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        this.leerDatosProducto(producto);
        
    }
}

leerDatosProducto(producto){
    const infoProducto = {
        imagen : producto.querySelector('img').src,
        titulo : producto.querySelector('h4').textContent,
        precio : producto.querySelector('span').textContent,
        id : producto.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-id'),
        cantidad : 1 
    }
    this.insertarCarrito(infoProducto);
}

insertarCarrito(producto){
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
    <td>
         <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
    </td>
    <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
    <td>${producto.precio}</td>
    <td>
         <a href="#" class="borrar-producto" data id="${producto.id}">X</a>
    </td>  
    `;
    listaProductos.appendChild(row);
    this.guardarProductosLocalStorage(producto);
}

eliminarProducto(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let producto, productoID;
    if(e.target.classList.contains('borrar-producto')){
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        producto = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
        productoID = producto.querySelector('a').getAttribute('data-id');
    }
    this.eliminarProductoLocalStorage(productoID);
}

vaciarCarrito(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    while(listaProductos.firstChild){
        listaProductos.removeChild(listaProductos.firstChild);
    }
    this.vaciarLocalStorage();
    return false;
}

guardarProductosLocalStorage(producto){
    let productos;
    productos = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
    productos.push(producto);
    localStorage.setItem('productos', JSON.stringify(productos));
}

obtenerProductosLocalStorage(){
    let productoLS;

    if(localStorage.getItem('productos') === null){
        productoLS = [];
    }
    else {
        productoLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('productos'));
    }
    return productoLS;
}

eliminarProductoLocalStorage(productoID){
    let productosLS;
     productosLS = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
     productosLS.forEach(function(productoLS, index){
         if(productoLS.id === productoID){
             productosLS.splice(index, 1);
         }
     });

     localStorage.setItem('productos', JSON.stringify(productosLS));
     localStorage.clear();
}

leerLocalStorage(){
    let productosLS;
    productosLS = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
    productosLS.forEach(function(producto){
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>
         <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
      </td>
      <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
      <td>${producto.precio}</td>
      <td>
         <a href="#" class="borrar-producto" data id="${producto.id}">X</a>
      </td>  
    `;
        listaProductos.appendChild(row);
    });

}

leerLocalStorageCompra(){
    let productosLS;
    productosLS = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
    productosLS.forEach(function(producto){
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>
         <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
      </td>
      <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
      <td>${producto.precio}</td>
      <td>
      <input type="number" class="form-control cantidad" min="1" value=${producto.cantidad}>
      </td>
      <td>${producto.precio * producto.cantidad}</td>
      <td>
         <a href="#" class="borrar-producto" data-id="${producto.id}">X</a>
      </td>  
    `;
        listaCompra.appendChild(row);
    });

}

vaciarLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.clear();
}

procesarPedido(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage().length === 0){
        Swal.fire({
            icon:'error',
            title:'Oops...',
            text:'La bolsa esta vacía, agrega algún producto',
            showConfirmButton: true
        })
    }
    else{
        location.href = "bolsa.html";
    }

}



    }
```

Y el que me está dando problemas de que no esta definido `new carrito` es `compra.js`, que es este:

```
    const compra = new Carrito();
    const listaCompra = document.querySelector('#lista-compra tbody');


    cargarEventos();

    function cargarEventos(){

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
    compra.leerLocalStorageCompra());
    }
```

Comment: Por favor agrega exactamente el error que obtienes y en dónde aparece.

Comment: En el navegador cuando entro en inspeccionar, el error me sale en consola de esta forma: Uncaught ReferenceError: Carrito is not defined at compra.js:1.  y en fuentes me marca que new carrito(); esta mal.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré una solución a Reference error not detected: is not undefined, lo que paso es que en el orden de los script que tenia en el html estaba de primero compra.js y después carrito.js

```
        <script src="assets/js/compra.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/carrito.js"></script>
```

Y la cambie a carrito.js y después compra.js los ordene de esta forma por cual utilizo primero ya con esto deja de salir ese error

```
        <script src="assets/js/carrito.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/compra.js"></script>
```

Pero ahora el código que se implemento que esta en carrito.js:

```
        leerLocalStorageCompra(){
        let productosLS;
        productosLS = this.obtenerProductosLocalStorage();
        productosLS.forEach(function(producto){
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        row.innerHTML = `
        <td>
         <img src="${producto.imagen}" width=100>
       </td>
       <td>${producto.titulo}</td>
       <td>${producto.precio}</td>
       <td>
       <input type="number" class="form-control cantidad" min="1" 
       value=${producto.cantidad}>
       </td>
       <td>${producto.precio * producto.cantidad}</td>
       <td>
         <a href="#" class="borrar-producto" data- 
         id="${producto.id}">X</a>
       </td>  
          `;
        listaCompra.appendChild(row);
       });
       }
```

Y también el código de compra.js no están funcionando, hay una forma para que funcionen? o mas bien una forma de obtener la información de carrito.js y que se imprima en compra.js ?

```
       const compra = new Carrito();
       const listaCompra = document.querySelector('#lista-compra tbody');

       cargarEventos();

       function cargarEventos(){

       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
       compra.leerLocalStorageCompra());
       }
```